# We are testing/evaluating CiviCRM Spark, but I can't get APIv4 to work

Tags: acl, apiv4, civicrm-spark

I'm not asking for tech support (sort of), I just need to know if the functionality is there. Checking the "Extensions" I see that API KEY MANAGEMENT is not Enabled.
I'm not sure if we are still in demo mode, or a Basic Spark subscription.

I am modifying an existing code-based program which implements HTTP/SSL connections.
I have implemented code to use both WildApricot and Airtable API's, so I am pretty familiar with the process.  I'm get NO DATA back from civicrm APIv4 when formatting what looks like well formed query. If I make it a bad HTTP request, I get an error.
I have tried both
Authorization: Basic
and
?_authx=Basic+B64(USER:PASS)
since I can't create API Keys. I don't know if this is the problem,
or maybe my ACL setup isn't right.
Again, I'm getting no error information back, just no data.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Since this relates to your Spark service I'd suggest asking on the ~spark channel on https://chat.civicrm.org/

Comment: Thanks, will do.